# setImageResource() programmatically to multiple ImageViews cause crash

Tags: java, android

I have 15 `ImageViews` created in the XML file and I have to set the images of them programmatically.

I have tried this code to do so:

```
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageOne);
```

And it works fine until I try to do it with all 15 `ImageViews`:

```
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageOne);
...
imageView15.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFifteen);
```

Now the application crash when it tries to load the view, because of the code above. And I get this weird message: `I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: try to reduce images size , may be help you !

Comment: The images has size 10-40kB

Comment: can you show how do you align the images?

Comment: `I get this weird message` - That's probably the least obscure message you can get... Are they JPGs or PNGs, what's their size?

Comment: Maybe you are running out of memory. Do you get any exception's stacktrace in your logcat? You may also use the profiler in AS to check of the memory usage spike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using scroll view, which is not supported to reusable views. If you want to create multiple imageviews and setting an images then you should use listview/RecyclerView etc which supports reusable view. Try to read about reusability.

Your application may also crashed because of you are loading large image which is requires more memory to show. Read about: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I am indeed using scroll view, I will try without it and see if thats whats causing the crash!

Comment: I did try and remove the scroll view, and now it just loads slowly instead of crashing.

Comment: Try to lower the image size to load it faster as mentioned in  Link: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: As S.K mentioned, lower the **image dimension size** and not the image file size. The images seems to be huge which is causing the main thread to do too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are delegating too work to MainThread so try to do it in a different way.
Use multi-threading programming if possible. It's useful to make your app logic separated from the UI. Use Java threads, AsyncTask or something similar. Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html)

Comment: Why is it if I set the images directly in the XML file everything works fine, but if I do it programmatically it crashes?

Comment: I don't know why in XML works, but programmatically your app is likely to be killed off by the system for blocking the main thread.